# Custom EXM UI on Sitecore 9.3

Tags: exm

I am using Sitecore 9.3.
I want to add one custom field on the review tab when sending a quick test email for EXM but can't find where source code to customize that. I saw that all UI is bin to minimize js file without source code.
Any suggestion about that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can change the components that are added on the Review tab if you open the Presentation details in the core database on the item `/sitecore/client/Applications/ECM/Pages/Messages/Regular/PageSettings/Tabs/Review/SubTabs/SendQuickTest`.
[image]

You can add new components to the Layout similar to how the Textbox component is added.
If you open the details you will see that an ID was specified for the textbox:
[image]

This ID is used in the `\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ECM\EmailCampaign.Client\Pages\Tabs\40-Review.js` and `\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ECM\EmailCampaign.Client\Component\Tab\ReviewTab.js` which send the textbox value when the button was submitted and also control the way the components are displayed in the tab.

When submitting the form the values are passed as a model to the `ExecuteSendQuickTest(SendQuickTestContext data)` action from the `ExecuteSendQuickTestController` (you can see the implementation in the `Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Server.Controllers.SendQuickTest.ExecuteSendQuickTestController` class).

The model is defined in the `Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Server.Contexts`:

```
public class SendQuickTestContext : MessageContext
  {
    [JsonProperty("testEmails")]
    public string TestEmails { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("variantIds")]
    public string[] VariantIds { get; set; }
  }
```

That specific Quick Test popup dialog is not possible to be changed as everything is hardcoded in the `\sitecore\shell\client\Applications\ECM\main.7d48bdcafd27fc1376be.bundle.js`. The only thing that you can change would be the translations for the elements which you can change on `/sitecore/client/Applications/ECM/Translations/Enter the email that you want to send quick test to`.

Comment: Hi Cristi,
I am working on sitecore 9.3. Seem It isn't used anymore.
I deleted the send quick test item but it still show on EXM UI.
I saw that the code is generated into angular js file (main.7d48bdcafd27fc1376be.bundle.js)

Comment: I have updated the answer, unfortunately only the text can be changed in that popup dialog.

Comment: Thanks Cristi!
This update of Sitecore 93 so strange :(